# How to merge lists with alternating elements?

Tags: python, concatenation

We have two lists `list1 = [10,30,50]`, `list2 = [2,4,6]`, and we want the output `[10,2,30,4,50,6]` (as opposed to `[10,30,50,2,4,6]`, which is easier to generate). The lists could be very long so the manual solution `list1[0] + list2[0] + list1[1] + ...` is not feasible for us.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm

Comment: thanks but I would like to avoid implementing my own merge algorithm, i assume there's an easier solution in python

Comment: concatenate and sort, or use `zip()` those are basically your options

Comment: Do you know that the lists can be sorted in this specific way, or could they be e.g. `[1,4,5]` and `[2,3,6]` and what should be the result in this case?

Comment: Are both lists guaranteed to always be the same length?

Comment: yes will always be the same length

Comment: no the lists cannot be sorted - this was a bad example using integers..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html#zip) grabs one item at a time from each list and pairs them up:

```
>>> list(zip(list1, list2))
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
```

You can then use a second loop to [flatten](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists) the pairs:

```
>>> [item for pair in zip(list1, list2) for item in pair]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Note that if the lists are different lengths `zip()` will ignore the extra items in the longer one.

Answer (score 0):

In case the lists are of integers, as appearing in the question you can simply combine the two lists, and then sort them

```
list1.extend(list2)
sorted(l1)
```

Comment: perhaps this is a bad example using integers because our actual list is of strings, the point is that the order of the lists matter. we cannot simply sort

Comment: Well, you didn't mention that in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
def sortLists(list1, list2):
    return sorted(list1+list2)
print(sortLists([1,2,5], [3,4]))
```

The output would be:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```